# Assigning IAM key to datacenter

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have made an IAM key to give access to Amazon SES SimpleEmailService.

However, it works only on us-east-1 (default) where I still am sandboxed, not on eu-central-1, where I am "unsandboxed".

Here I get the message **SimpleEmailService::listVerifiedEmailAddresses(): Sender - InvalidClientTokenId: The security token included in the request is invalid**

I have made it 12 hours ago, could it still be waiting to propagate?

I can not see anywhere where the keys are assigned to which datacenter, if they are at all.

In the mean time, I have asked to get unsandboxed on us-east-1, but that takes time...

Comment: What is the message that you get when you try to use the key?

Comment: I have edited the text to include the error message.

Comment: IAM users are global, and before writing this comment I verified that I could create a new user an invoke `aws ses list-identities` in both `us-east-1` (where I have SES configured) and `eu-central-1` (where I don't). It worked as expected.

Comment: I'm going to assume that you are running the same program, with the same configuration and _just_ changing the region. Of course, it's always worth calling `sts:GetCallerIdentity` to verify that the keys are correct.

Comment: However, one other possibility is that [ListVerifiedEmailAddresses](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/API_ListVerifiedEmailAddresses.html) is not supported in `eu-central-1` (it's marked as deprecated), and the error is being reported as an invalid key. I recommend trying [ListIdentities](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/API_ListIdentities.html) instead.

Comment: It's not only ListVerifiedEmailAddresses that fails.
Also :"getSendQuota(): Sender - InvalidClientTokenId: The security token included in the request is invalid", Or :sendEmail(). Just changing from eu-central-1 to us-east-1 makes everything work. But now I'm out of sandbox on us-east-1, so I don't need to worry anymore....My list is only around 1000 addresses bi-monthly, so not a huge amount of mail having to cross the ocean.

Comment: In that case I recommend contacting AWS support. There could be some issue with your account.

Comment: Actually, I do have one more question: are you assuming a role to perform these actions? I was thinking that message was from an invalid long-lived (user) access token, but it's also reported when an assumed-role session token is invalid. If you're using the same credentials and just changing the region, it shouldn't matter, but it would perhaps open up some other lines of investigation.

Comment: No, it's a freshly generated key. with a user created a week or so ago.